# htaccess and php files - treating all files as php?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mamp

I have a website on localhost, latest MAMP build.
The subfolder is test2.

This is its .htaccess:

```
DefaultType text/html
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
```

Is this the correct way to ensure files get treated as both HTML and PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Write it as:

```
<Files *>
  DefaultType text/html
  DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

All files in dir and subdirs will be opened as PHP.